# Mongoose returns null array when populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a webapp with mongoose and nodejs. This is the first time i'm using mongoose and nodejs so i'm not quit good at it.

I have a person model:

```
var PERSON = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    zipcode: {type: String, required: true},
    city: {type: String, required: true},
    street: {type: String, required: true},
    address: {type: Number, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    type: {type: String, enum: ['lid', 'passant'], required: true},
    ships: {
      type: [{
        name: {type: String, required: true},
        length: {type: Number, required: true},
        type: {type: String, required: true},
        picture: {type: Buffer, required: false}
      }],
      required: false
    },
    user: {
      type: {
        userName: {type: String, required: true},
        password: {type: String, required: true},
        passwordKey: {type: String, required: true},
        roles: {type: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'role'}], required: true}
      },
      required: false
    }
  },
  {
    collection: 'PERSON'
  });
```

And the rol model:

```
var ROLE = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true}
  },
  {
    collection: 'ROLE'
  });
```

When i'm trying to run a find query on the person model, I want to populate the user.roles array. But as a result it remains empty.

```
 / GET a specific person by id or type/
  server.get('/api/person/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    if (helper.isValidObjectID(req.params.id)) {
      person.findById(req.params.id).populate("user.roles").exec(function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            res.status(404).json(err);
          } else {
            res.status(200).json(result);
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }, function (req, res, next) {
person.find({type: req.params.id}).populate('user.roles').exec(function (err, result) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(404).json(err);
  } else {
    res.status(200).json(result);
  }
});
```

});

and as a result i get:

```
{  
   "_id":"553f79d4f1481c0c14b42d59",
   "name":"Wilco Boogert",
   "zipcode":"4305RH",
   "city":"Ouwerkerk",
   "street":"baalpapenweg",
   "address":2,
   "email":"wilcoboogert17@gmail.com",
   "type":"lid",
   "user":{  
      "userName":"wboogert",
      "password":"sha1$168fd599$1$502b965cb083ebdfcafb17e655455ef63779e1a1",
      "passwordkey":"kfjvlksdfm",
      "roles":[  

      ]
   },
   "__v":0,
   "ships":[  
      {  
         "name":"titanic",
         "length":269,
         "type":"Olympic-klasse",
         "_id":"553f79d4f1481c0c14b42d5a"
      }
   ]
}
```

The orginal object in the database is:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "553f79d4f1481c0c14b42d59"
    },
    "name": "Wilco Boogert",
    "zipcode": "4305RH",
    "city": "Ouwerkerk",
    "street": "baalpapenweg",
    "address": 2,
    "email": "wilcoboogert17@gmail.com",
    "type": "lid",
    "user": {
        "roles": [
             {
            "$oid": "5522996f0fff331ed03cae6c"
             }
        ],
        "passwordkey": "kfjvlksdfm",
        "password": "sha1$168fd599$1$502b965cb083ebdfcafb17e655455ef63779e1a1",
        "userName": "wboogert"
    },
    "ships": [
        {
            "name": "titanic",
            "length": 269,
            "type": "Olympic-klasse",
            "picture": "<Binary Data>",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "553f79d4f1481c0c14b42d5a"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

so as you an see the roles is empty. And I search the web but i cannot find what the problem is. Can annyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace this line :

```
roles: {type: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'role'}], required: true}
```

with this one :

```
roles: {type: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ROLE'}], required: true}
```

In fact, the reference must be the exact same name as it's defined :

```
collection: 'ROLE'
```

It's case sensitive.

Comment: First of thanks for your quick response, I have changed the things you picked out. But when i change it the result stays the same, with other words the return array remains empty